# Making a 15kg table to move around without drilling

Tags: table

I have a table weight about 15 kg (length: 250 cm, width: 60 cm, height: 80 cm). Currently, the table does not have ball bearings or wheels on the four legs. The table is currently empty with nothing on top of the table and nothing inside the drawers

My current concern and intention is that I wish to make it portable (so that I can move it about without having two person to carry it). I was also concern if the wheels can take the weight of the table if I start to put things on the table or into the drawers.

Also, I prefer a solution that require little efforts as possible. I have no intention to drill holes on the table and I also do not wish to saw the table too.

May I know how do I go about doing it such that I can make a unmovable table to a portable one.

Comment: How do you feel about drilling the legs of the table?

Comment: What type of surface must the table move over?

Comment: Greebo is right, the correct answer here is to drill holes in the bottom of the legs and slide casters in...

Comment: @James, I beg to differ as Comintern mention that there are cup casters that does not require drilling holes.

Comment: assuming the table has round legs yes that is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really going to be a caster that requires *no* drilling, but [cup casters](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=cup%20casters&tbm=shop) generally only require 1 screw hole to secure them to the side of the leg:

[image]

Assuming that you can find some with a good fit, these don't require the huge hole and reinforcement that a stem caster would, and are much easier to attach to furniture legs than plate casters.

The image above shows a round caster, but square cup casters are also available.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. I never thought that there are cup casters exist since my neighborhood shop only sell normal casters that require drilling on the table.

Answer (score 2):

Well if drilling is not an option than that eliminates castors, which would be the logical choice. If you have hard surface flooring you could apply furniture pads (high density felt) to the feet and just slide it around.